# Filter object by keys which h

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{house_id+street_id+school_id: {...}, house_id2+street_id2+school_id2: {...}, ...}
```

So, each key of the object is a combination of a house_id a street_id and a school_id separated by '+' sign.

I want to be able to filter the object given a street_id, so for example, for the given object:

`{40+30+20: { name: "john" }, 41+31+20: { name: "eli" } }` and the street_id being `30`, the returning object would be:

```
{40+30+20: "john"}
```

How can I do that filtering?

Comment: What part of it are you stuck on? What has your research turned up? If you've made an attempt to do it, what does that attempt look like? Where does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way

```js
let obj = {'40+30+20': { name: "john" }, '41+31+20': { name: "eli" } }

let result = Object.keys(obj).filter(e => e.match(/^.*\+30\+.*$/) != null).reduce((a, b) => {
    a[b] = obj[b];
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var data = {
  '40+30+20': { 
    name: "john" 
  }, 
  '41+31+20': { 
    name: "eli" 
  } 
};

var search = '30';
var r = Object.keys(data).filter(function(key) {
  return key.split('+').some(function(p) {
    return p === search;
  });
}).map(function(key) {
  var o = {};
  o[key] = data[key];
  return o;
});

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the filter function and a regular expression:

```
var myObj = {'40+30+20': { name: "john" }, '41+31+20': { name: "eli" } };

function filterByStreet(obj, streetId) {
    var filteredKeys = Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => {
        var patt = new RegExp("[^+]+[+]" + streetId + "[+][0-9]+");
        return patt.test(key);
    });

    var outObj = {};

    for(filteredKey of filteredKeys) {
        outObj[filteredKey] = obj[filteredKey];
    }

    return outObj;
}

var filteredObj = filterByStreet(myObj, 30);
console.log(filteredObj);
```